Fixed points of diffeomorphism of odd dimensional manifold with non-degenerate fixed points
Let $M$ be a closed smooth odd-dimensional manifold and $f : M \to M$ a diffeomorphism with only non-degenerate fixed points. I am asked (on a practice qualifying exam) to show that the number of fixed points of $f$ is even.
What I have so far is that the number of fixed points of $f$ has the same parity as the algebraic intersection of the graph of $f$ with the diagonal $\Delta$ in $M \times M$. So if $f$ is isotopic to the identity, then this latter intersection number is the self-intersection number of $\Delta$, which is equal to the Euler characteristic, which for $M$ is zero. I am confused about what to do if $f$ is not isotopic to the identity.
Edit: I think it suffices to show that the Lefschetz number is even, and I think it should be possible to show that $\mathrm{tr}(f_*|H_k(M;\mathbb{Q})) = \mathrm{tr}(f_*|H_{n-k}(M;\mathbb{Q}))$ using the fact that $\mathrm{tr}(ABA^{-1}) = \mathrm{tr}(B)$ for any square matrices $A$ and $B$. I would still like to see this argument more carefully written.

Are you expected to know the Kunneth theorem (homology of a product of spaces at least in the case of smooth manifolds)? If you know it, the proof is not hard, just think about the mod 2 homology class of the graph of $f$.

@Moishe Kohan Thank you for your help. I am expected to know the Künneth theorem. So far I have that the mod 2 homology class of the graph of $f$
in $M \times M$ is $g_*[M]$ where $g : M \to M \times M$ is the map $x \mapsto (x,f(x))$. Is this zero in $H_n(M \times M; \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, where $n = \dim M$? If so, that would be nice, because $[\Delta] \cdot [\mathrm{graph}(f)]$ would vanish in $H_0(M \times M;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$. The Künneth theorem in this case tells us that $H_n(M \times M) = \bigoplus_{i+j=n} H_i(M) \otimes H_{n-i}(M)$, but I am unsure how to use it.

No, it projects to generators of $H_n$ in both factors. Proving it will be half of your work. Then you figure out how this homology class decomposed  with respect to the Kunneth formula.

Thank you again. Given that the class of the graph of $f$ only has terms in $H_n(M) \otimes H_0(M)$ or $H_0(M) \otimes H_n(M)$, I understand how to finish the proof. Regarding showing the "given ..." statement, I was trying to use the fact that the maps $M \times M \to M$ given by $(x,y) \mapsto x$ and $(x,y) \mapsto f^{-1}(y)$ in homology map the class of the graph of $f$ to the fundamental class of $M$. Is this helpful or enough?

It is helpful but not enough.
